# Convert text file to CSV on shell

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv, json

I would like to convert a text file into CSV format.

Here is an excerpt from the file:

```
{"Outdated":false,"Watt":233,"Timestamp":1669647142,"A_Plus":6523.896,"A_Plus_HT":4494.82,"A_Plus_NT":2029.076,"A_Minus":8841.63}
{"Outdated":false,"Watt":235,"Timestamp":1669647152,"A_Plus":6523.896,"A_Plus_HT":4494.82,"A_Plus_NT":2029.076,"A_Minus":8841.63}
{"Outdated":false,"Watt":235,"Timestamp":1669647596,"A_Plus":6523.896,"A_Plus_HT":4494.82,"A_Plus_NT":2029.076,"A_Minus":8841.63}
{"Outdated":false,"Watt":233,"Timestamp":1669651191,"A_Plus":6524.496,"A_Plus_HT":4495.42,"A_Plus_NT":2029.076,"A_Minus":8841.63}
{"Outdated":false,"Watt":276,"Timestamp":1669654797,"A_Plus":6524.816,"A_Plus_HT":4495.74,"A_Plus_NT":2029.076,"A_Minus":8841.63}
{"Outdated":false,"Watt":437,"Timestamp":1669658393,"A_Plus":6525.901,"A_Plus_HT":4496.825,"A_Plus_NT":2029.076,"A_Minus":8841.63}
{"Outdated":false,"Watt":362,"Timestamp":1669661992,"A_Plus":6526.732,"A_Plus_HT":4497.656,"A_Plus_NT":2029.076,"A_Minus":8841.63}
{"Outdated":false,"Watt":471,"Timestamp":1669665603,"A_Plus":6527.062,"A_Plus_HT":4497.986,"A_Plus_NT":2029.076,"A_Minus":8841.63}
```

The structure resembles a JSON file, but unfortunately the structure does not quite match. I have already used this tool (https://github.com/alingse/jsoncsv), but unfortunately I get error messages because of the wrong structure.

How can I turn it into a CSV file?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an example of the expected result.

Comment: You have had a lot of good answer. Has none been good for you? If yes, please indicate which

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me it seems easier and safer to first convert to proper `json`, then use a parser (e.g. `jq` or `jsoncsv` that you have tried) instead of writing your own parser.

Convert to json by simply adding `[` in then first row and append `]` after the last row and a comma to every except the last row.

```bash
sed '1s/^/[/;$!s/$/,/;$a]' file
```

Then [convert to `csv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32967407) using `jq`

```bash
jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ]])[] | @csv'
```

And put it together:

```bash
$ sed '1s/^/[/;$!s/$/,/;$a]' file | jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ]])[] | @csv'
"Outdated","Watt","Timestamp","A_Plus","A_Plus_HT","A_Plus_NT","A_Minus"
false,233,1669647142,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,235,1669647152,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,235,1669647596,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,233,1669651191,6524.496,4495.42,2029.076,8841.63
false,276,1669654797,6524.816,4495.74,2029.076,8841.63
false,437,1669658393,6525.901,4496.825,2029.076,8841.63
false,362,1669661992,6526.732,4497.656,2029.076,8841.63
false,471,1669665603,6527.062,4497.986,2029.076,8841.63
```

Comment: You could avoid the sed by using --slurp (or -s) I think

Answer (score 9):

Each row of your input is a valid JSON object - so if you don't care about CSV headers, you could simply deconstruct them back into arrays and pass them through the `@csv` filter:

```
$ jq -r '[.[]] | @csv' file
false,233,1669647142,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,235,1669647152,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,235,1669647596,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,233,1669651191,6524.496,4495.42,2029.076,8841.63
false,276,1669654797,6524.816,4495.74,2029.076,8841.63
false,437,1669658393,6525.901,4496.825,2029.076,8841.63
false,362,1669661992,6526.732,4497.656,2029.076,8841.63
false,471,1669665603,6527.062,4497.986,2029.076,8841.63
```

If you *do* care about headers, it's more complicated. The best I could come up with is:

- *slurp* the whole file into an indexed array of rows
- perform a reduction of the array of rows, initializing it with the keys extracted from the 0<sup>th</sup> element

You now have an array-of-arrays, with a header array at the top, that may be mapped back to an array of CSV (and finally to individual CSV rows):

```
$ jq -r --slurp 'to_entries |
    reduce . as $row ([.[0] | .value | keys_unsorted]; . + [$row[] | .value | to_entries | map(.value)]) |
    map(@csv) | .[]
  ' file
"Outdated","Watt","Timestamp","A_Plus","A_Plus_HT","A_Plus_NT","A_Minus"
false,233,1669647142,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,235,1669647152,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,235,1669647596,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,233,1669651191,6524.496,4495.42,2029.076,8841.63
false,276,1669654797,6524.816,4495.74,2029.076,8841.63
false,437,1669658393,6525.901,4496.825,2029.076,8841.63
false,362,1669661992,6526.732,4497.656,2029.076,8841.63
false,471,1669665603,6527.062,4497.986,2029.076,8841.63
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a very used data format, [Json lines](https://jsonlines.org/)

You can use [Miller 6](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and run

```
mlrgo --ijsonl --ocsv cat input.jsonl
```

to get

```
Outdated,Watt,Timestamp,A_Plus,A_Plus_HT,A_Plus_NT,A_Minus
false,233,1669647142,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,235,1669647152,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,235,1669647596,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
false,233,1669651191,6524.496,4495.42,2029.076,8841.63
false,276,1669654797,6524.816,4495.74,2029.076,8841.63
false,437,1669658393,6525.901,4496.825,2029.076,8841.63
false,362,1669661992,6526.732,4497.656,2029.076,8841.63
false,471,1669665603,6527.062,4497.986,2029.076,8841.63
```

---

In the useful comment below, there is a note about the way to do it in Miller 5:

```
mlr --ijson --ocsv cat input >output
```

Comment: Nice! even Miller 5.6.2 seems to work, with the generic `--ijson` format: `mlr --ijson --ocsv cat file`

Comment: thank you @steeldriver , I add it on my answer

Answer (score 3):

The type of data you provide in your example is called **[Newline delimited JSON](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec)**(*AKA **NDJSON***) ... There are tools that support it natively like [`in2csv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/in2csv.1.html) which is provided by the **[csvkit](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/csvkit)** package ... so install it first like so:

```
sudo apt install csvkit
```

Then, specify the format with the option `-f ndjson` and simply use it on your file like so:

```
in2csv -f ndjson file
```

That should result in:

```bash
Outdated,Watt,Timestamp,A_Plus,A_Plus_HT,A_Plus_NT,A_Minus
False,233,1669647142,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
False,235,1669647152,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
False,235,1669647596,6523.896,4494.82,2029.076,8841.63
False,233,1669651191,6524.496,4495.42,2029.076,8841.63
False,276,1669654797,6524.816,4495.74,2029.076,8841.63
False,437,1669658393,6525.901,4496.825,2029.076,8841.63
False,362,1669661992,6526.732,4497.656,2029.076,8841.63
False,471,1669665603,6527.062,4497.986,2029.076,8841.63
```